# Can't retrieve Token in Django model

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework, token

I am trying to retrieve Token from rest_framework.authtoken.models as there is token created for user when he/she signs up. (It can be seen in my django admin panel in the picture below). I am facing issue as trying to get Token in my Django model to create profile for user. Error is:

```
rest_framework.authtoken.models.DoesNotExist: Token matching query does not exist.
```

What causes error? 
**My models.py file is here:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = Token.objects.get(key='token string').user
    bio = models.CharField('Bio', max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Picture of Django admin panel and user Tokens:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3fmt.png)

Comment: Your user connection on the Profile looks very strange. It mixes a query with the actual model. It should be: 

user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

Comment: But i am using React JS in my frontend which provides token for logged in user. So i think i cant use Django default auth User model directly

Comment: I should get user from token instead?

Comment: @TheKaizer how should i get my User object from React JS frontend?

Comment: I would return the token directly when logging in against the login service you provided. There you can configure the fetching of the token. This should not be done in the Profile model as your question stated.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Figured it out later and now its working well.